# Как формируется запрос у jQuery.getJSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Подскажите, не могу понять откуда берется часть урла.
Вот функция:

```
function BWGet()
{
    jQuery.getJSON("http://example.ru/pages/bw_get.php?key=JzEyMjkzY2JkNzNjZGkgf6YxMzc1ODRhZjc5N2M5hD4=&type="+jQuery("#type").val()+"&srid="+jQuery("#srid_select").val()+"&sid="+jQuery("#sid_select").val()+"&reason="+jQuery("#reason").val()+"&callback=?", function(data){
        if(jQuery("#format").val() == "minus")
        {
            if(jQuery("#type_radio input[type='radio']:checked").val()=='black')
            {
                var t = (data["items"]).join("\n-");
                if(t!='') t = '-'+t;
            } else
            {
                var t = (data["items"]).join("\n");
            }
            jQuery("#result").val(t);
        } else if(jQuery("#format").val() == "set")
        {
            jQuery("#result").val((data["items"]).join(","));
        } else 
        {
            jQuery("#result").val((data["items"]).join("\n"));
        }
    });
}
```

А вот запрос, который видно в сниффере трафика:

```
    http://example.ru/pages/bw_get.php?key=JzEyMjkzY2JkNzNjZGkgf6YxMzc1ODRhZjc5N2M5hD4=&type=black&srid=2&sid=11&reason=all&callback=jQuery1102025274819379493363_1474878640640&_=1474878640645
```

Подскажите где создается вот эта часть урла callback=jQuery1102025274819379493363_1474878640640&_=1474878640645 ?

Comment: Вам стоит почитать о [JSONP](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)

Comment: Я работаю с интерфейсом этого сайта через десктопное приложение, поэтому мне нужно дублировать запросы. Но не могу найти где генерится часть урла.

Comment: Эта "часть урла" генерится jquery. Почему и как - см. по ссылке выше.

Comment: Это я понял. Имя функции генерируются по какому то алгоритму? Или я могу подставить рандомные значения? jQueryXXXXXX_XXXXX_=XXXXX ?

Comment: @Artem по алгоритму

Comment: Вы можете подставить туда все что захотите, хотите рандомное значение, хотите фикс-ное. Серверу это без разницы. Это нужно для клиента, чтобы вытащить нужные данные из ответа, т.к. ответ для JSONP не является JSON, это JSON, обернутый в вызов функции.

Comment: hindmost, спасибо за развернутый ответ. Вопрос решен.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как описали в комментариях в вашем коде используется jsonp, т.е технология которая позволяет использовать кросс-доменные ajax запросы. Но важный момент в этой технологии в том, что за корректную работу отвечает не только клиент но и сервер. Если использовать код который в вашем примере то jquery сама генерирует имя функции которая будет передана на сервер, а сервер в свою очередь должен обернуть ответ в эту функцию и вернуть клиенту, ну а на клиенте будет вызван обработчик который в getJson описан.

Пример с пользовательской jsonp функцией (В роли серверного языка программирования используется php).

Клиентская часть

```
$.ajax({    
    type     :     "GET",
    url      : 'url',
    data     : {},
    dataType : "jsonp",
    jsonp    : 'callback',
    jsonpCallback  : 'doSomething',
    success        : function(message){
    }
});

function doSomething(data) {
   console.log(data);
}
```

Серверная часть

```
<?php
echo $_GET['callback'] . '(' . "{'property' : 'value'}" . ')';
```